# Xcode Build Error "Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code"

Tags: ios, xcode

I am building my project on iPad (device not the simulator) and it always throws an error at the very last step. I did restart, rebuild, clean up but still it appears to be there. In simulator its working fine no errors at all but only in the device.

**`Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code`**

I there a way to get rid if this?

Comment: What does the script do?  (You can expand the error message in the Report Navigator for details.)